# How many 4 sequences which sums to zero?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose you have a commutative group G of N elements wih a law +

I want to prove that, the number of :
- $f_1,\ldots,f_q$ pairwise distincts elements of G
- $g_1,\ldots,g_q$ pairwise distincts elements of G
- $h_1,\ldots,h_q$ pairwise distincts elements of G
- $z_1,\ldots,z_q$ pairwise distincts elements of G
such that the $f_i+g_i+h_i+z_i=0$ for all $i=1..q$

is close to what we should expect : $\frac{((N(N-1)\cdots(N-q+1))^4}{N^q}$ since there is 4 sequences of $q$ distinct numbers and there is q equations.

Thank you

Comment: Do you know if analytic combinatorics could solve this problem ?